# Is there an syntax error in the WSDL link im calling? If ref is present [...]

Tags: xml, powershell, webservice-client

I was provided a webservice URL that ends in "?WSDL" and that gives me access to an XML file over the web.

My task is to send values over to the webservice and get a response back, but I'm having issues connecting to it with PowerShell. I managed a connection last week but after Easter holiday there has most likely been some changes on the webservice form another party. Now I'm getting the following error when I try to connect to the webservice.

See image.

[image: The error message: if ref is present, all of [...] must be absent]

I've tested without the parameters: `-UseDefaultCredential` and `-Namespace`, the error is still the same

```
$HACWS = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $UriLong
```

```
New-WebServiceProxy : Schema item 'element' named 'RadarDeployResponse' from
namespace 'urn:RadarDeploymentTNS'. If ref is present, all of <complexType>,
<simpleType>, <key>, <keyref>, <unique>, nillable, default, fixed, form, block,
and type must be absent.
At line:2 char:16
+ ...  $WsShort = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://hssdas515:8090/Ivory/soa ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-WebServiceProxy], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebServiceProxy
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved my error by contacting the creator of the Webservice I was trying to connect. Apparently there was a syntax error within a xml element. The error message was very explanatory.